# Using a configuration intersection in ivy

Tags: ant, ivy, artifactory

I would be very thankful for your help.

We use ant\ivy to manage our dependencies.
And we want to download a minimum quantity of modules: only those are needed for build.
I try to use a configuration intersection, but I got a not expecting ivy behavior.

https://ant.apache.org/ivy/history/latest-milestone/ivyfile/dependency.html

> since 2.1 It is also possible to define dependencies on configurations intersection. A configuration intersection is defined using a '+' sign to separate the configuration (eg 'A+B' means the intersection of configuration 'A' and 'B'). In that case only artifacts and dependencies defined in both configurations in the dependency will be part of the master configuration defining the dependency on the configuration intersection.
>
> Configuration intersections can also be used when specifying the confs to resolve.

build.xml file:

```
<project xmlns:ivy="antlib:org.apache.ivy.ant" xmlns:e="http://ant.apache.org/ivy/extra" name="test" default="get">
    <target name="get" description="-->Downloads all artifacts and prepare it">
        <ivy:resolve file="ivy.xml" conf="${conf}" />
    </target>
</project>
```

ivy file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ivy-module version="2.0" xmlns:e="http://ant.apache.org/ivy/extra">
    <info module="test" organisation="main" revision="1.0"/>
    <configurations>
        <conf name="release"        e:axis="download_type" />
        <conf name="dev"            e:axis="download_type" />

        <conf name="client"         e:axis="product"/>
        <conf name="server"         e:axis="product"/>
    </configurations>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency org="main" name="zlib" branch="trunk" rev="1.2.8.+" conf="dev->*;client->*"/>
    </dependencies>
</ivy-module>
```

Case 1:

> ant -Dconf="dev+server"

Case 2:

> ant -Dconf="server+dev"

I expect that the results are same in first and second case: zlib shouldn't be downloaded, because the intersection of "Dev" and "Server" confs is nothing.
But I get:

- in case 1: Zlib is not dowloaded
- in case 2: Zlib is dowloaded

Where is my misunderstanding?

Thanks

PS. Version of ivy is 2.4.0

Comment: I've just found the issue about this theme: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/IVY-1093  But status of this feature is not clear. I need a workaround.

Comment: Ivy will download and cache files associated with each configuration. I don't understand what you are saving by making your ivy resolve operation configurable. Seems to me you'd be best advised to use fixed configurations that match your build's classpaths and use something like Nexus or Artifactory to provide additional upstream caching if network latency is an issue.